# PyList_GetItem() returning a reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-c++, pyobjc

I am using the PyHelper class that I found [HERE](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820116/Embedding-Python-program-in-a-C-Cplusplus-code/)

My python script is returning a list and in C++ I can call PyList_Size() and successfully get the size but when I try get item it returns a very large number which I assume is a address reference rather than the actual list element

Here is my code[image]

args is defined as CPyObject args = PyTuple_New(1);

This is the Output
[image]

I am expecting to see the actual elements which are in the list that I can then assign to a string in order to use them in C++ without having to use PyObject further

Comment: Please post the code not images. Also, consider creating a *MCVE* ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Anyway you have the *PyObject\**. You need to check what kind it is and based on that call specific methods that will get you the actual data.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank  you for the response , How exactly to I check what kind it is? It should be a PyList right? thats what my py script is returning and I can check the size of the PyList I just cant extract the list data

Comment: *PyList\_GetItem* returns whatever element was inserted in the list (*int*, *str*, *float*, list, tuple, ...). There are functions named *Py\*_Check* (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_Check) that need to be called in order to cast the object to the appropriate specialized type. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with *PyObjC*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved thanks to help from CristiFati
the issue was that the PyScript was returning a list of dictionaries which meant in C++ the use of both PyList functions and PyDict functions was needed in order to parse the data.
For example
PyList_Size(pValue) in order to get the size of the list
but then in order to access the dictionaries in the list the following code was needed
CPyObject pListItem = PyList_GetItem(pValue, i);
PyDict_GetItemString(pListItem, "content")